# Any information on the Dalvik Machine?

Tags: android, dalvik

I know this might not be very appropriate to ask here. But I want to ask in hopes you might be able to point me somewhere so I don't mess up :)

I have to write an assignment on 8-15 pages about the Dalvik Virtual Machine. I am asking for source material.

Do you know any specific sources (besides Wikipedia and it's references) that you would point to perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a fan of google code, and you can get information directly from the horse's mouth so to speak, (especially the wiki page): [Dalvik](https://code.google.com/p/dalvik/)

Also, from a java implementation standpoint, I would recommend this tutorial: [Dalvik-on-Java](https://code.google.com/p/android-dalvik-vm-on-java/wiki/Tutorial1)

Comment: Oh, is that like a Dalvic vs Java thing? That would be perfect. Or if you have anything on that, it would be amazing!

Comment: Here's a couple of sites that seem to be good for comparing Dalvic vs Java: [comparison-of-dalvik-and-java-bytecode](http://forensics.spreitzenbarth.de/2012/08/27/comparison-of-dalvik-and-java-bytecode/) and [dalvik-virtual-machine-vs-java-virtual](http://androidjayavelu.blogspot.com/2011/06/dalvik-virtual-machine-vs-java-virtual.html) Also I came across this document on the architecture of the Dalvic Machine: [Dalvic-architecture](http://show.docjava.com/posterous/file/2012/12/10222640-The_Dalvik_Virtual_Machine.pdf)